# Autoreload div with a php code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

With a javascript (ajax) I load a div every 7 seconds. In that div that we introduced a php code that checks if a condition is met (a simple if, if x = 1 {displays a different image} else {display another image}. Everything is working properly until the condition is satisfied. It displays the image I need to display only if condition is met, but after 2-3 seconds disappears and it no longer appears. Why is this happening?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function () {
            $('#refresh').empty();
            $('#caseta').load('http://example.com/<?php echo $_SERVER['
                REQUEST_URI '];?> #caseta');
            return false;
        }, 7000);
</script>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<div id="caseta"> 

<?php
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $select=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE data='$today' AND  ip='$ip'"));

    $id=$select['id'];

    if($int_nou==$int_vechi+1){ ?>

        <div style="z-index:4;position: relative; ; top: 110px; left:170px; background-color: white; width:270px; height:150px;">
            <img src="img0.png" style="width:243px; height:56px; margin-left:13px;"  /> </a>

        </div>
    <?php   $update="UPDATE `test` set status='1' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($update);   }
    else { ?>
        <div style="z-index:4;position: relative; ; top: 110px; left:170px;     background-color: white; width:270px; height:150px;">
            <img src="img1.png" style="width:243px; height:56px; margin-left:13px;"  /> </a>

        </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be having a problem the way you are using your single quotes here, also there is a trailing space after REQUEST_URI that should not be there.  You also should not need the domain url, since it should be on the same host, otherwise the issue you may be facing would be cross site scripting.

change this:

```
 $('#caseta').load('http://example.com/<?php echo $_SERVER['
            REQUEST_URI '];?> #caseta');
```

to this:

```
$('#caseta').load("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?> #caseta");
```

Additional Info

change to this and see what gets printed in console:

```
$('#caseta').load("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?> #caseta", function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

This will determine if you are actually getting anything returned from your PHP script.

Comment: If this doesnt help, please post the html and php.

Comment: sorry, got busy.  I posted an edit to try and get some more info.